# If two vector subspaces are perpendicular each other, then the intersection between them is trivial

Tags: linear-algebra

I asked to prove that claim that:
if *U,W* subspaces of *V* and *U⊥W*, then the intersection between *U,W* trivial

How can I prove it?

Comment: What is your definition of two subspaces being ``perpendicular'' to each other? That is a good starting place.

Comment: I meant that U⊥W @JWP_HTX

Comment: @Eran what is your definition of $U \perp W$?

Comment: @Eran Your comment is just a notation for the two subspaces being perpendicular.  It's not a definition.  According to your class or your textbook, what is the definition of the two subspaces being perpendicular?  What does it *mean*?  Once you've got that definition in hand, you've got a place to start with your proof

Answer (score 0):

I think your definition of subspace orthogonality is
$$
\forall x\in U,\forall y \in V, x^Ty=0
$$
Let's say the intersection of the two subspace $U\cap V$. Assume existing an element $w\in U\cap V, w\not=0$ then there exist an example violating the orthogonality condition.
$$
w\in U,w\in V, w^Tw=\|w\|^2\neq 0
$$
Then this contradiction tells you there is no non-zero element in $U\cap V$